# Can not find compilation library location for package 'Newtonsoft.Json'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-mac

Using Visual Studio for Mac (Community 7.3), I am trying to run the sample project from Lynda.com's "Learning ASP.NET Core MVC" Chapter 3 which introduces "Render HTML with Razor".

I builds find but when I try to load in browser I get the error below:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: Can not find compilation library location
>   for package 'Newtonsoft.Json'
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths()
>
> Stack Query Cookies Headers InvalidOperationException: Can not find
>   compilation library location for package 'Newtonsoft.Json'
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths()
>   System.Linq.Enumerable+d__157.MoveNext()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.MetadataReferenceFeatureProvider.PopulateFeature(IEnumerable
>   parts, MetadataReferenceFeature feature)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateFeature(TFeature
>   feature)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRoslynCompilationService.GetCompilationReferences()
>   System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(ref T
>   target, ref bool initialized, ref object syncLock, Func
>   valueFactory)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRoslynCompilationService.get_CompilationReferences()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRoslynCompilationService.Compile(RelativeFileInfo
>   fileInfo, string compilationContent)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.CompilerCache.CreateCacheEntry(string
>   relativePath, string normalizedPath, Func compile)
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.CompilerCache.GetOrAdd(string
>   relativePath, Func compile)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorPageFactoryProvider.CreateFactory(string
>   relativePath)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.CreateCacheResult(HashSet
>   expirationTokens, string relativePath, bool isMainPage)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.OnCacheMiss(ViewLocationExpanderContext
>   expanderContext, ViewLocationCacheKey cacheKey)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.LocatePageFromViewLocations(ActionContext
>   actionContext, string pageName, bool isMainPage)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext
>   context, string viewName, bool isMainPage)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.CompositeViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext
>   context, string viewName, bool isMainPage)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewResultExecutor.FindView(ActionContext
>   actionContext, ViewResult viewResult)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult+d__26.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+d__32.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+d__31.MoveNext()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+d__29.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+d__23.MoveNext()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+d__18.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+d__4.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   ExploreCalifornia.Startup+<>c+<b__3_0>d.MoveNext() in
>   Startup.cs
>                   await next(); System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+d__6.MoveNext()
>
> Show raw exception details

Comment: Check the Nuget packages of the project. If Newtonsoft.Json is not installed, install it!

Comment: Which version? I have over 20 to choose from, from 3.5.8 to 10.0.3
My project target framework is .Net Core 1.0.

Comment: In the Packages.Config file of the project, you will find all the details you need.

Comment: In the Packages.Config file all I see is:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="RavenDB.Client" version="3.5.3" targetFramework="net462" />
</packages>

Anyway I installed Newtonsoft.Json version 10.0.3
Now I get: Can not find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.CSharp'
So I installed  Microsoft.CSharp (4.4.0) but the error doesn't change.